# How would I turn a 4 legged character into a playable race?

Tags: dnd-5e, homebrew, races

To elaborate on this topic.This is for a 5E campaign. I own a art piece that is a 4 legged animal.I want to work with my DM to turn it into a playable race. We, (the DM and I) have attempted this before to no success. Thus i turn to you, the reader. If there is a method for turning a 4 legged character into a playable race it would be awesome!

The technicalities that we have discussed over are as follows. How does the character interact with the world? I.E money, weapon wielding, magic using (casting as well), are they able to talk? Speed, and combat stats, would those get a bonus or a hindrance.For example, would they get a magic bonus if they were created magically? Or would a 4 legged playable race of house cat size and shape get a hit to its strength as it has a severe size disadvantage?

Those are just some thoughts and things we have noticed about having a Home brew playable race that is 4 legged. If any of you have any idea's, again we turn to you and your helpful words or direction to possible create this playable race.

Comment: Do you have access to the Dungeon Master's Guide?

Comment: Welcome to rpg.se! Take the [tour](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/tour) when you have time. This question could be better if you define what you mean better. 4-legged *what*? Dog, Blink Dog, or Awakened Dog? What is the reason that the creature qualifies as a PC?

Comment: Possibly a picture would help a lot, too. How big is it? How smart is it? Does it have arms?

Comment: Yes I do have access to the DMG. The picture in question is my profile picture at the time of this post. But for those that can not see it. Its a house cat in simple terms. Shape and size in all. As for the reason to be a PC is for the purpose of a one shot. There is no reason in a ongoing session to make this into a PC. As for smarts I was either thinking a magically touched creature or a magically created creature could by pass some of the limitations. But not all.

Comment: *"The technicalities that we have discussed over are as follows. How does the character interact with the world? I.E money, weapon wielding, magic using (casting as well), are they able to talk?"* And to what conclusion did you come?

Comment: The conclusion was, that I and my DM could not figure it out. Thus we asked here.

Comment: "How does the character interact with the world? I.E money, weapon wielding, magic using (casting as well), are they able to talk? " — You imply that the character doesn't have arms or a mouth, which is more significant to that problem than having four legs. Centaur's have no problems doing any of those things.

Comment: @SailtheCurious Do you have the level up process figured out? That is also an integral part of creating a custom race that might or might not be able to have "classes"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Start with an existing creature

As the *(Dungeon Master's Guide, 5th ed., p285-6)* recommends. I recommend you reflavor the blink dog *(Monster Manual, 5th ed., p318)*. It's intelligent, has but one attack, and you can easily just remove its teleportation ability, if you feel the need. Its CR is the same as a goblin however, so it might be balanced as-is.

Resize it as needed; your cat might be either small or tiny. Use the cat's or jackals physical stats and damage, for tiny and small creatures respectively.

Consider having them have a language like the blink dog does; able to understand other tongues, but not pronounce them. This might be akin to a feline version of Chewbacca from Star Wars. Alternately, they could be completely capable of speech; it'd be easier for party communication.

Regarding item usage, barding might be useful, but lack of fine manipulators requires handed assistance to don or doff the armor. Weapons and shields would be useless, as would boots, generally.

It could use mouth and both forepaws a rough equivalent to 2 hands, but only for gross rather than fine work. Paws and teeth are OK for carrying or opening a simple latch, but sewing or crafting would be impossible.

Spellcasting is *possible* with such a race, as nagas and flameskulls all cast without somatic or material components, and the sphinx casts without materials. However as with all of this it's not actually a general rule, just extrapolation from other rules or stats. In fact the ability to cast without material components ability might partially or completely replace the Teleportation ability of the blink dog. Although just having a focus on your character should do the same usually (not for expensive spells). (Sphinx seems kinda fun as a possible relative of such a creature).

For a one-off, balance is *less* important; just play nice, and have fun.

Comment: So from what I've been able to gather is that broad manipulation would be do-able. What about magic? Like wizard magic and warlock magic. Would i be able to cast such spells? (As a new ish player i have don't have as much experience with how spells work)

Comment: @SailtheCurious Good question! I forgot about that. Monsters without hands can cast, at least via innate spellcasting, such as the couatl (5eMM, p43), and the flameskull can cast as a 5th level spellcaster, but is called out as not requiring components. Haven't found a general rule; you'd have to make it up, I think.